# Developing chat Module

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am developing online Chat application in asp.net. I am facing a problem like suppose there are two users starts communication. When first user write a message in javascript based chat box Then ajax request goes to server. BUt how I open second user chat box so he responce the first user message?

Comment: Not a useful question, I'm afraid. It's far, FAR too broad.

Comment: Its not too broad and its a real question. He's asking how to show user 2 when user 1 is typing a message or sends a message. I'll post an answer.

Comment: You are asking people here to develop an entire chat app I think ! Please be specific

Answer (score 2):

When a user sends a message, an AJAX request will be made to your server and you'll probably save the posted message to a database. You can also have an ajax request made every X seconds that checks for any newly posted messages on the server, and if there are any, it shows them to the user.

Alternatively you can use a technology called Comet, through which your server can 'push' a response to the clients to notify them whenever a new message has been posted.

Answer (score 2):

You should research long polling and web sockets. These allow your clients to have updates pushed to them more effectively. You could poll the server every x seconds, but it would be wasteful of resources.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at SignalR, an async signaling library for .NET which would be perfect for a chat-application:

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Scott Hanselman has a good example on his blog:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx