# I want to develop Chat Application in EXT.NET

Tags: c#, .net, ext.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Developing chat Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753678/developing-chat-module)

I need your help for developing chat application in .net framework 3.5.

I am able to archive to view online users in my chat window. now I  want to sent message to another online user instantly as soon as I send message to My friend the chat message should be displayed instantly.

I am able to insert chat message to my database but Don't know how to sent message instantly to my friends chat window.

Comment: But the Question has not been answered yet. So do you have any solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are speaking of a web application.  In this case, you need to use a method of AJAX polling to call your server from both clients at a given time interval (1 second, for example).

Alternatively, if you don't mind using only HTML 5 browsers (except for IE9) you can use Websockets to *push* messages to the client.  Here is an open source .NET framework just for that with a chat application built out:

```
http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can put a kind of timer in your webpage pulling the last messages from the server, using ajax, each... 1 second? half a second? something like that.

You can find some information about this here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp and for ext.net http://examples.ext.net/#/TaskManager/Basic/Overview/

Hope it helps.